# Create cron jobs to repeat every X units of time starting on an arbitary unit

Tags: cron

I have a cron job on CentOS that I want to execute every 3 minutes but I have many other cronjobs that run at every 3 minutes starting from 0, 3, 6, 9...

So, to avoid my server getting too overloaded, I wanted some of my crons to run at every 3 minutes but starting at 1 minute and so on: 1, 4, 7...

My crons are usually like this:

```
*/3 * * * *
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try this online utility   https://helloacm.com/crontab-generator/

Answer (score 19):

1-59/3 is the more typical and concise way to specify it, meaning "every 3 minutes starting from 1".

Answer (score 7):

In addition to heemayl's answer, you could list the minutes you want, though it's less compact and probably more error prone than the existing way:

```
1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58 * * * * some_command
```

Comment: nice, I didnt know that! :) And what would this do 1,4,7 2,5 * * * ? Would it work as expected, I mean, would this cron run at 2 hour 1 minute, 4 minute, 7 minute and at 5 hour 1 minute, 4 minute and 7 minutes?

Comment: @Samul yup, that's just what it would do

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sleep 60` as the first command so that the command you want to run, actually runs after 1 minute while keeping the `cron` time as `*/3`:

```
*/3 * * * * sleep 60 && some_command
```

Comment: nice alternative but does it add any overhead to cron? I already have about 140 crons running on this server and they are all very optimized. Will using this sleep 60 create any overhead? I mean, if I use it on 70 of my crons, and keep the other 70 without sleep, will it be "easy" to my server run?

Comment: @Samul Each `sleep 60` means an extra process that will be finished after 60 seconds automatically (given everything goes well)..depending on your system's load this could or couldn't be a problem..in normal cases and stable systems this shouldn't be a problem even with 140 jobs..

Comment: Also, `sleep` literally just sleeps. All it does is (basically) ask the OS to wake it up after the specified amount of time. Don't believe me? Try `strace sleep 60` to see what it *really* does.